# How do i allow a user to export a report to pdf from power bi service

Tags: powerbi

I created a report and have shared it with the individual who requested it. I have the capabilities to export the report to a pdf from the power bi service, and need to see if i can let that user do the same. Anyone know how to accomplish this, and if not, is there an alternative that will easily capture the report at that time and allow them to take notes of it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be controlled in the Tenant Settings of the Admin Portal.

[image: Admin Portal]